# Capture image from camera into form or html5 canvas

Tags: html, image-processing

I need to capture an image from a webcam (tethered camera, etc.) into a form or html5 canvas so that I can save the image to the server. Also, I would like to be able to preview the image live in the page.

For example, I have a browser running at a registration check in station. I would like to take a picture of the attendee currently standing in front of the table, and submit that image into the database. Then I can use that image to print the attendee's badge with their picture on it.

I'm using rails and paperclip, though I doubt that matters.

Anyone done this before, or have some ideas how to do it?

Comment: For others that will come here from Google: the pure HTML5 solution now works in all current browsers. See http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/ .

Comment: @HubertOG http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/#toc-screenshot doesn't work for me

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a plugin for jQuery entitled 'jQuery Webcam Plugin' that provides a friendly and easy way to interact with a webcam. It actually relies on a small flash component (unfortunately), but it does a great job of making the interaction easy - as well as providing functionality to copy imagery direct into an HTML5 canvas.

Again, it's unfortunate that it relies on Flash, but I think any reliable solution is going to need flash at this point in time.

The plugin is available here: http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/

Comment: Excellent solution. Agreed that the flash req is a necessary evil.

Answer (score 3):

At present, if you want to interact with a web cam from a web page you need to look at using a plug in. Flash has a mature interface to web cams, so it would be my first choice of tool.

There used to be a spec for native web cam support in HTML 5, but it has been spun out into [its own, independent, specification](http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/getusermedia.html). Currently [there is no browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=getusermedia) for it outside of [experimental Opera builds](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/playing-with-html5-video-and-getusermedia-support/).

Comment: unfortunately I agree that flash is your best bet here.

Comment: Now Chrome 18+ supports this. See example in www.html5rocks.com

Answer (score 1):

Android >=3.0 (on plenty of tablets and one phone soon) is supposed to support this. Searching for "html media capture" and "device api" will get you a lot more information.

On the not-even-alpha bleeding edge side, there are things like webrtc and the mozilla rainbow plugin.